# Node version issue in Multisite Sitecore jss application in Azure

Tags: jss, azure

I have 2 jss apps deployed to azure. Both are built on node 12.15.0 and I have WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION as 12.15.0 in azure app settings but Only one of the apps is getting loaded at a time. For the other I am getting attached error. I have tried to change node version but it didn’t. Any suggestions ?

[image: Node error]

Comment: Are you trying to load both apps in the same instance?

Comment: Yes Richard, we have 2 jss apps which uses the same Sitecore instance and same azure app service. Once I restart the app and load 1 site, that site continues to work but the other one doesn’t.

Answer (score 1):

I made below change and the issue was fixed,

Changed LaunchWithDebugging from true to false in Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Node.config